# how to get sshv2 remote host key using openssh

Tags: ssh, openssh

I am implementing sshv2 client from application side using openssh lib. I have to connect with remote host and get the host key and need to store in known_host file.

In case of sshv1 if we send from client side below command we will receive sshv1 ras key,
SSH-1.0-xxxxx/authApp_1.0

But I am not sure how to get host key from remote server in case of sshv2, what are the commands do we need to exchange in case of sshv2 to get host key from remote server?

Can we get any reference code or document for this? Kindly suggest me .